# Если убрать мышь за пределы элемента textBox и щелкнуть по форме, то у меня срабатывает обработчик. Имеется ли такое стандартное событие в C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Допустим у меня есть элемент textBox, если я убираю мышь за пределы этого элемента и щелкаю по форме или по элементу формы, то у меня срабатывал бы обработчик. Имеется ли такое стандартное событие в C#?

Comment: Обработчик -- это средство. А какого эффекта вы хотите достичь этим обработчиком? Может есть другие пути для этого?

Answer (score 1):

Либо обрабатывайте пару событий: у текстбокса `MouseLeave` (мышь покидает его) и последующий щелчок на форме - `Click`, `MouseClick`, `MouseDown`.

Либо, вероятно, вам нужны события фокуса: у текстбокса `Leave` (потеря фокуса) и событие `Enter` (приобретение фокуса) у другого контрола. Тут нужно учесть, что сама форма не может получать фокус, это умеют лишь контролы, предназначенные для ввода.
Хотя у формы есть событие `Activated`, зажигаемое, когда на неё переходит управление от других окон.